# Aspect for Spring JDBC

Tags: spring, spring-aop, spring-jdbc

Is that possible to define Spring AOP aspect to Spring JDBC ? To be specific, I am trying to setup a logger for NamedParameterJdbcTemplate to log SQL queries. Below is my XML configuration.

```
<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect id="aspect4" ref="sqlLoggingInterceptor">
        <aop:pointcut expression="execution(* org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate..*(..))" id="pointcut3" />
        <aop:around pointcut-ref="pointcut3" method="profile" />
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

And below is my interceptor.

```
@Aspect
@Component
public class SQLLoggingInterceptor {
    private final Map<String, SqlTiming> sqlTimings;

    public Object profile(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
    //logger
    }
}
```

It throws below below exception while creating the context, seems to be not able to autowire proxy in place of NamedParameterJdbcTemplate, where NamedParameterJdbcTemplate is autowired in lot of DAO implementations.

```
15:06:32,566 INFO  [STDOUT] ERROR [ContextLoader] - Context initialization failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Error creating bean with name  'com.application.dao.FileStorageDAO': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
Could not autowire field: private org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate com.application.dao.FileStorageDAOImpl.jdbcTemplate; 
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate field  
com.application.dao.FileStorageDAOImpl.jdbcTemplate to $Proxy166
```

Comment: instead of using NamedParameterJdbcTemplate try to used [JdbcOperations](http://www.gotoquiz.com/web-coding/programming/java-programming/profile-sql-statements-in-java-spring/)

Comment: @user23123412 Thanks for the info. This is the example I try with. Below is my jdbc template configuration. `<bean name="com.application.dao.JDBCTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource">
   <ref bean="com.application.dao.DataSource"/>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean name="com.application.dao.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg index="0">
   <ref bean="com.application.dao.DataSource"/>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>` Is it ok to inject datasource ?