# AspectJ Aspect used for Spring JDBC is not invoked

Tags: aspectj, spring-aop, spring-jdbc

Ok. When I tried to setup Spring Aspect for Spring JDBC, I got Exception as in  [Aspect for Spring JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536282/aspect-for-spring-jdbc).

Now I changed code and config a bit and I do not see any exception. Still my aspect is not called.

Here is the configuration.

```xml
<bean name="com.application.dao.JDBCTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource">
      <ref bean="gov.usda.fsa.pscao.clg.cops.dao.DataSource"/>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean name="com.application.dao.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg index="0">
      <ref bean="com.application.dao.JDBCTemplate"/>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

....
<context:component-scan base-package="com.application.spring.aspect"></context:component-scan>
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true"/>
<bean name="sqlLoggingInterceptor" class="com.application.spring.aspect.SQLLoggingInterceptor" />
<aop:config>
    <aop:aspect id="aspect4" ref="sqlLoggingInterceptor">
    <aop:pointcut expression="execution(* org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcOperations.*(String, ..))" id="pointcut4" />
    <aop:around pointcut-ref="pointcut4" method="profile" />
    </aop:aspect>
</aop:config>
```

Aspect implementation:

```java
@Aspect
@Component
public class SQLLoggingInterceptor {
    public SQLLoggingInterceptor() {
            System.out.println("SQLLoggingInterceptor created...");
    }

    public Object profile(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
    //do logging
    }
}
```

My dependencies are (Spring version 3.2.8):

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>aspectj</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.3</version>
</dependency>
```

And, JDBCtemplate is invoked like this:

```java
NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
jdbcTemplate.queryForList(SQL_STRING, parametersMap);
```

Considering the fact NamedParameterJdbcTemplate wrapper for JdbcOperations, I assume whenever I execute query like above, it should be able to invoke aspect. But the aspect is not called. Do I miss something here ? I would greatly appreciate any inputs or comments. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you resolve this problem? I'm facing the same problem. I really appreciate your comments.